# How to find sequential text patterns-text mining

Tags: python, pattern-matching, text-mining

I have many sequences of actions commands collected from users, something like "forward, backward, jump, shoot". There are some command sequences are reasonable, validated by an expert.  How can I use those "reasonable action commands" to predict whether a new action command sequence is reasonable?

I've tried n-gram analysis find the the most frequent patterns, but I am looking for another ML methods(to build a model) for its detection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably should look into decoder models. https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate

You could take a pre-trained decoder model and fine-tune it with your dataset. The text generation task is exactly what you would need. You would need to be familiar with Python and DL frameworks (pytorch, tensorflow etc..) but the APIs are pretty straightforward.